# Website not scaling at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am building a website in bootstrap for work and i just can't get it to scale down when the resolution changes at all

http://www.vccb.co.za/demohome/

i am using Bootstrap v3.3.4.
i also have the viewport meta tag aswell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="Vericred, Credit bureau, tracing, search, people" />
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>VCCB Home</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- JQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-63126052-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

```
<body id="page-top" style="width:100%;position:relative;" class="index">

<!-- Navigation -->
<div id="menuContainer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"> 
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="position:relative;width:100%">   
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>    

            <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll" style="position:absolute;margin-left:18%">
                <h2 class="section-heading slant">We are not just another bureau,</h2>
                <h3 class="slant">because you are not just another consumer</h3>
                <img id="menuLogo" src="img/full_size_logo.png" style="margin-top:-18%;margin-left:140%;height:100px;width:280px;visibility:visible"/>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-top:8%">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right multi-level" role="menu" style="margin-top:-5.2%;margin-left:14%;width:100%;position:relative">
                    <li style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;overflow:hidden;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="Home.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;overflow:hidden;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a id="vis" class="page-scroll" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>

                    <li  style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a href="ConsumerFriend.html">Consumer Friend</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="dropdown" style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Business Partner<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu" >
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Services and Products</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a target="_blank" href="consumer.html">Consumer Contact Data</a></li>
                                            <li><a target="_blank" href="ConsumerBehaviouralData.html">Consumer Behavioural Data</a></li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </li>                              
                            </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown" style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Legal<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a target="_blank" href="docs/PAIA_MANUAL.pdf">PAIA Manual</a></li>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href="docs/DisclaimerAndPrivacyPolicy.docx">Disclaimer and Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Affiliations.html">Affiliations</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>

                    <li style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;overflow:hidden;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.vccb.co.za/Trace">Client Login</a>
                    </li>
                        <li style="border: 3px outset #202020;border-radius:0.5em;overflow:hidden;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4%;background-color:red;">
                        <a target="_blank" href="/RequestAccount.html">Sign Up As A Client</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:3.8%;">
                        <a href="#" style="line-height:0px;padding-top:8px;margin-left:-17px;"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="margin-top:25%"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%;margin-top:3.8%;">
                        <a href="#" style="line-height:0px;padding-top:8px;margin-left:-17px;""><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="margin-top:25%"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%;margin-top:3.8%;">
                        <a href="#" style="line-height:0px;padding-top:8px;margin-left:-17px;"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="margin-top:25%"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>

<section id="CompInfo" style="font:14px/18px Times New Roman;color:#64676b;background-color:black;height:700px;width:70%;margin-left:15%;margin-top:1%;position:relative;">
        <label style="color:white;font-size:10em;margin-top:20%;margin-left:20%;position:relative;">TUTORIALS</label>
</section>

<!-- Services Section -->
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">The main benefits to the consumer whose information is kept on our data base are:</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Contactability</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Improve your contactability.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-money fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Pension Pay-outs</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Receive outstanding pension pay-outs.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Avoid Legal Action</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Chance to pay outstanding debt and avoid legal action.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-medkit fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Consumer Rehabilitation</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Rehabilitating consumers.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Stay Updated</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Receive important information timeously.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-child fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Add Value</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">This adds value to the consumers overall wellbeing.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="request" class="btn btn-m" style="color:white;float:right;margin-right:6%" type="button">Sign Up As A Client</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label style="color:black;float:right"> Already a tracing customer? Click <a style="color:black;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" href="https://www.vccb.co.za/Trace">HERE</a> to login.</label>
    </div>
</section>

<div style="visibility:hidden">Vericred, Credit bureau, tracing, search, people</div>

<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">About</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">VeriCred Credit Bureau (Pty) Ltd is the newest registered Credit Bureau in South Africa in terms of the National Credit Act No 34 of 2005, with registration number NCRCB21.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="timeline">
                    <li class="in">
                        <div class="timeline-image">
                            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>1990-1994</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body">
                                <p class="text-muted">VeriCred Credit Bureau was first established in 1990 in Bophuthatswana as a credit bureau. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted in">
                        <div class="timeline-image">
                            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>1994-2007</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">South Africa and the National Credit Act</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body">
                                <p class="text-muted">After 1994 VeriCred Credit Bureau was incorporated into the New South Africa and continued to operate until the National Credit Act was implemented in 2007 which significantly changed the face of the industry. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="in">
                        <div class="timeline-image">
                            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="img/about/3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>2012</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Vericred Credit Bureau</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body">
                                <p class="text-muted">In 2012 VeriCred Credit Bureau was revived and a new credit bureau was established. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted in">
                        <a href="#services">
                            <div class="timeline-image">
                                <h4 style="color:White">Be Part
                                    <br>Of Our
                                    <br>Story!</h4>                                
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">Phone:</label>     <a style="color:white" href="tel:0878034798">087 803 4798</a> </h4>
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">Fax Number:</label>  086 604 1273</h4>
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">Email:</label>     <a style="color:white" href="mailto:tracesupport@vccb.co.za">info@vccb.co.za</a></h4>
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">Website:</label>   <a style="color:white" href="www.vccb.co.za">www.vccb.co.za</a> </h4>
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">General Enquiries:</label>     <a style="color:white" href="mailto:info@vccb.co.za">info@vccb.co.za</a> </h4>
                <h4 style="color:white"><label style="color:red">Website:</label>   <a style="color:white" href="mailto:disputes@vccb.co.za">disputes@vccb.co.za</a> </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="button" onclick="SendMail()" class="btn btn-xl" style="color:white">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<footer>
    <div class="container" style="width:auto">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4" style="width:4%"> 
                <img id="back-top" onclick="$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);" src="/img/top.png" title="Click to go to the top." style="width:100%;height:100%;border-radius: 50%;-webkit-border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50%; box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1)"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" style="width:25%">
                <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact us</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <a target="_blank" href="docs/Terms  Conditions and Privacy Policy.pdf">Disclaimer and Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs/PAIA_MANUAL.pdf" target="_blank">PAIA Manual</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" style="width:20%;margin-left:12%;">
                <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" style="width:25%;margin-left:14%">                  
                <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; www.vccb.co.za 2016</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/agency.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/ContactUs.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
    var once = true;
    var count = 0;
    $('#back-top').fadeOut();

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var centerY = Math.max(0, ((jQuery(window).height() - jQuery(elem).outerHeight()) / 2)
                      + jQuery(window).scrollTop());

        centerY = parseFloat(centerY) + 300;

        var elementTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(elem).height();

        return elementTop <= centerY && elementBottom >= centerY;
    }

    jQuery(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        jQuery(".in").each(function (index, element) {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(element)) {
                jQuery(element).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#vis", function () {
        $(".in").css("opacity", "1.0");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#giveMail", function () {
        alert("Please fill the form in and email it to tracesupport@vccb.co.za");
    });


    $(document).on("click", "#request", function () {
        window.location.href = "/RequestAccount.html";
    });

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The only resolution that everything is as it should be is at my screen resolution of 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use bootstrap for responsive design, you need to specify the number of columns for different sizes. Bootstrap is split into 4 breakpoints:

- col-xs-* (extra small)
- col-sm-* (small)
- col-md-* (medium)
- col-lg-* (large)

It is a mobile first framework, so specify the size for extra small first, then specify the point at which the size should change. Eg. If you wanted a div to be 12 columns at extra small, small, and medium, but only 6 columns on large, you would do `<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">`.

You can specify all breakpoints, but if you don't, it will default to the smallest one specified.

In your code, you have set the size for only one breakpoint, and you have not gone mobile-first, so it is not responsive.

---

The reason the navbar is not collapsing is because you have not put the button inside the `div.navbar-header`. There needs to be a button with `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#idOfNav"`. This is what appears on smaller screens and what toggles the navbar to collapse/expand. For example:

```
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" type="button">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

And this would go in the `navbar-header`.

Here's a codepen of a default bootstrap navbar, so you can see how it should be: http://codepen.io/Xhaerithius/pen/ZQPqNz

Also, you can use a bootstrap navbar for your footer as well. Just change the class of `navbar-static-top` to `navbar-fixed-bottom`. Your footer needs to be responsive too! :D

Comment: i tried that just now, i can see how that can work, but in this case its not working, my first problem is getting the navbar to resize or collapse into the menu icon, i added the code for it but its just not happening. The only things on my page not scaling is the header and the footer, and the placeholder i left for tutorials.

Comment: If you use tools like firebug in your website, you will notice that the code for the menu icon is not present.

Comment: @Arno4Jackie Sorry, I only skim-read your code xD. I;ve edited my answer. I tested it on your site, so it should work if you just copy and paste it in the right place, and change the id to the correct id (in your case `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. the problem i am having now is that when the menu goes to mobile view my sub-menu is not working correct, clicking it closes the menu and hover does nothing. I also did as you said with the footer and it didn't change anything

Comment: Can you make a codepen of it? (Or at least update your site with your new code)

Comment: sorry for the late response, here is my codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwMgeY